# How to sort a queue in place in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

You are just not allowed to create new data structures.

Note: This is not a homework question, i am preparing for interviews and I came across this question

Comment: As many pointers as I want in Java, eh?

Comment: "Complexity is not important" I don't Like that....

Comment: while(!isSorted(queue))shuffle(queue)

Comment: Why not simply reuse the priorityqueue?

Comment: because priority queue uses a heap.. the point of this question is that you are not allowed to use anything but the queue itself

Comment: selection sort :D why would someone ask such a question ? . The question must be can u do it in O(NlogN)

Comment: well its a little different than selection sort because its a queue

Comment: Don't let your interviewer find out that this is how you prepare for interviewers. If you don't know Java well enough to be able to intuitively deduce the answer to such a basic question, I know I certainly wouldn't hire you. It's a disservice to your interviewers for you to pretend that you're qualified for a job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Pop two elements from the queue.
2. Compare them.
3. Push the lesser one in the queue.
4. Pop another element.
5. Keep repeating from step no. 2.
6. After n-1 comparisons, you will get the largest element in the queue.
7. Push it and repeat the above n-1 times. At each iteration, you need to make one less comparison as the last element is already the maximum.

This will sort the queue in descending order. For ascending order, simply reverse the comparison results.

**Note: The above algorithm is incomplete and a small step is missing. I leave that to you to identify and fix.**

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `take`takes an element from front of queue, `offer` inserts an element to fron of queue.

```
sort q :
   return if q is empty
   a = take q
   sort q
   insert a q

insert a q:
    if q is empty
      offer q a
      return
    b = take q
    if a < b
      offer q b
      offer q a
      return
    insert a q
    offer q b
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

1. poll() and offer() one by one every object (.size() times) and save the minimum (*current minimum*)
2. poll() and offer() one by one every object and scan for next bigger after *current minimum*. If you can't find next - stop.
3. poll() and offer() one by one untill you offer your *next after current minimum*, don't poll it
4. poll() and offer() one by one untill you poll you *current minimum*
5. poll() you *next after current minimum*. It's your current minimum now. Go to step 2